# Morph linear graph to log graph by distorting UVs?

Tags: uv, shader-nodes, mathematics, audio

Hi Blender enthusiasts.

I've been trying to understand how the ffmpeg [shoswpectrumpic](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrumpic) function works. It allows you to generate a spectrogram from an audio file using either a linear, or logarithmic scale for the frequency.

I've generated a tone getting higher at a constant rate, and generated 2 spectrograms from it :

- one using a [linear scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cyg7.png) for the frequency
- and another with a [log scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LrJW.png)

I want to understand what kind of operation ffmpeg applies when using the "log" option.

My idea is to distort the Y axis on the UVmap so I can 'morph' the linear image to the log image. But I don't know what operation I should apply to go from linear to log ?

[image]

If you have any idea of how to approach this problem please share, I've been at it for hours...

Here's my blend file : [image]

edit : ok I've found an operation that seems to work, but I don't understand why...

[image]

The operation goes like this :

```
y = 10^(-3*(1-y))
```

Anybody knows why this particular operation works ?

Comment: Have you tried the logarithm operation in the math node?

Comment: I tried it and it does curves the UVs, but it goes the wrong way, and the curve doesn't match the one I'm trying to copy...

Comment: Your file has been deleted, can you share it again? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @taiyo it should be good now !